# Converting PDF to text

Tags: windows, pdf, document-converter, file-converter

I have multiple PDF documents that contains a lot of text. I want to use these texts in a search engine I'm developing. This search engine is using software that cannot work with PDF files, but can work with formats such as JSON, XML, and text documents.

What I want to do is convert the text content of a PDF into text documents (formats such as JSON, XML, TXT). It would also be easier for my work if it could convert the text content from a single PDF to multiple text documents. For example one document per article.

It would also have to work with Windows 10.

Comment: Have you looked into Microsoft Store ? They have these apps there ?

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia, pdftotext (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext) is an open source command line utility that does conversion from PDF to plain text. And there are Windows binaries for download on the official page (http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html), both 32 and 64 bit included.

Sadly, I have not needed to do something like you do, so this is purely researched information. My whole experience with it is I downloaded the tool pack (15 minutes ago), and used pdftotext to generate a single TXT file from a PDF I know very well, and there were no issues I could see.

It allows to select a starting and last page for the conversion, so it may be of use for your "multiple documents" requirement, but dividing the documents by content and not by page... I think you won't have luck finding something like that; a custom script that acts upon the TXT files might be better for that.

Answer (score 1):

The LEADTOOLS ePrint can be used to convert among different document and file types, including PDF to text. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of this software).

You will need a PDF reader, such as the free Adobe Acrobat Reader, and LEADTOOLS ePrint printer driver to be both installed on the same Windows PC (works on Windows 10 and other desktop versions).

If the original PDF contains actual text (searchable), the conversion can be done directly by printing from the PDF reader program to the virtual printer driver.

If the source files contain images of text, you can also do the conversion, but you will have to use the OCR features in ePrint.

You can find a free evaluation of this program on the website here:
https://www.eprintdriver.com/Download

Free email support is also available even during evaluation.